# C# and MongoDriver - How to get values from foreign collection (aggregate + lookup)?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've got a problem with getting values from foreign collection in C#. 
In this case I can easily get values from list:

```
var gamesList = gamesCollection.Find(_ => true).ToList();
foreach (var item in gamesList)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");

}
```

But when I'm using aggregate with lookup function, I can not access to values from foreign collection. 
Here are my two collections which I try to join:

```
public class GameModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<String> Type { get; set; }
    public string GameMode { get; set; }
    public List<String> Platform { get; set; }
    public string Production { get; set; }
}

public class FavouriteGameModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId UserID { get; set; }
    public ObjectId GameID { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the part of problematic code:

```
var joinedFavGamesList = favouriteGamesCollection.Aggregate().Match(x => x.UserID == loggedUser[0].Id).//ToList();
                        Lookup("Games", "GameID", "_id", @as: ("myAlias")).
                        Project(
                            new BsonDocument { { "_id", 0 }, { "myAlias.Title", 1 } }
                        ).ToList();
```

Is there any way to invoke to myAlias.Title? I want only this value to display, but i get: 
{ "myAlias" : [{ "Title" : "Some Game" }] }

I will be greatful if someone could look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my choice would be to join/lookup using the `AsQueryable` interface like so:

```cs
var favGames = favCollection.AsQueryable()
                            .Where(fg=> fg.UserID== "xxxxxxxxxxx")
                            .Join(gameCollection.AsQueryable(), //foreign collection
                                  fg => fg.GameID,              //local field
                                  gm => gm.ID,                  //foreign field
                                  (fg, gm) => new { gm.Title }) //projection
                            .ToList();
```

with aggregate interface:

```cs
public class JoinedGameModel
{
    public GameModel[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var favGames = favGameCollection.Aggregate()
                   .Match(fg => fg.UserID == "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                   .Lookup<FavouriteGameModel, GameModel, JoinedGameModel>(
                       gameCollection, 
                       fg => fg.GameID, 
                       gm => gm.ID, 
                       jgm => jgm.Results)
                   .ReplaceRoot(jgm => jgm.Results[0])
                   .Project(gm => new { gm.Title })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine! By the way, is it possible to solve this using my code? I mean using aggregate with lookup? I can't find solution for this. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @innKeep10 added aggregate method to the answer